# Non-uniform scaling

Tags: logic, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I have 10 numbers $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_9, x_{10}$ which sum to a total of $1,000$.

I want to scale these numbers so the total is equal to $10,000$, however I don't want them to scale exactly.

I'm not sure exactly (will depend on the output) of the variance required in the scaling but I'm thinking somewhere $\approx10\%$.

Does this question make sense? Can anyone provide a solution on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the 10 numbers?

Comment: [84, 170, 107, 136, 206, 117, 45, 21, 112, 2] - I want to make it non-trivial to tell the exact original numbers, but also retain the approximate percentages they represent.

Comment: You should probably post some sort of explanation of your overall goal.  Explain what exactly the modified scaling is supposed to achieve.  Otherwise, there's really no way for anyone to answer your question.  For example, it's unclear based on what you've written why simply multiplying all of the numbers by 10 is undesirable.

Comment: I do not understand what you just said. What do you mean to scale exactly? Scale relative to what?

Answer (score 1):

1. Multiply each number by a randomly chosen real number between $9$ and $11$.
2. Scale the resulting numbers by the same factor to make their sum equal to $10000$.

If the result must be integer, add step (3) rounding and (4) adjusting some numbers by $\pm 1$ to bring the sum to $10000$ again, as necessary.